# Android 4.4.2 Kitkat can not send a request with HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, http, connection, android-4.4-kitkat

In my app I send a POST request to a server via an HttpURLConnection. But since I updated my Samsung S4 to Android 4.4.2, I don't receive any requests in the server.

Here is my code:

```
private static void send (final String uri, String SomeText) throws IOException {
  final URL url = new URL (uri);
  final HttpURLConnection conn;

  // setup the connection
  conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
  conn.setDoInput (true);
  conn.setDoOutput (true);
  conn.setUseCaches (false);
  conn.setRequestMethod ("POST");
  conn.setChunkedStreamingMode (0);

  final OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream ();
  final OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter (os);
  final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (osw);

  try {

    writer.write (SomeText);

  } finally {
    writer.flush ();
    writer.close ();
    conn.disconnect ();
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any HttpURLConnection change for KitKat?

When I use DefaultHttpClient everything works fine and I can receive the request by the server. But I still like to use the HttpURLConnection, because the app is testet with this kind of connection.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware if you're using emulator. I had such problem as I was using Proxy. BTW. have you added to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Also to work with response use corresponding class
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html

Comment: The permission is already added to this app. The app worked fine with Android 4.2.2. The problems occur with the version update to Android 4.4.2. BTW the server is indepently programmed in another language and got all requests before updating the android phone.

Comment: Quite weird try to use HTTP request/response instead of HTTPURLConnection probably that will help...